# Windows Phone App MVVM, updating UI from an async method in the viewmodel

Tags: asynchronous, mvvm, win-universal-app

I have the following ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public bool Processing
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private IEnumerable<ExternalLoginModel> _authenticationProviders;
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<ExternalLoginModel> AuthenticationProviders
    {
        get
        {
            return _authenticationProviders;
        }
        set
        {
            _authenticationProviders = value;               
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => AuthenticationProviders);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel(IAuthenticationService authService)
    {
        Processing = true;
        authService.GetSupportedAuthenticationProvidersAsync().ContinueWith(authProviders => { PopulateAuthProviders(authProviders.Result); });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="authProviders"></param>
    private void PopulateAuthProviders(IEnumerable<ExternalLoginModel> authProviders)
    {
        AuthenticationProviders = authProviders;
        Processing = false;
    }
}
```

The property  **AuthenticationProviders** is bound to a ListView.  The problem is that once the **AuthenticationProviders** are populated through the Async method (via) the constructor the ListView does not get updated.  I tried **RaisePropertyChanged** but then I get the error **The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.**  This makes sense as well since its actually calling from another thread.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Why aren't you scheduling the continuation delegate to run on the calling thread, i.e. add TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() to ContinueWith and then call RaisePropertyChanged ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This literally contains the answer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630646.aspx

Basically you have to use

```
    DispatcherHelper.Initialize
```

And then whenever you need to update you need to use
    DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI

Given is the sample

```
    DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => AuthenticationProviders);
            });
```